# IndexError Python

Tags: error404

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    # dominio
    Lx=5
    Ly=8

    # discretizar
    Nx=5
    x=np.linspace(0,Lx,Nx)
    dx=Lx/(Nx-1)

    Ny=6
    y=np.linspace(0,Ly,Ny)
    dy=Ly/(Ny-1)

    xmesh,ymesh=np.meshgrid(x,y,indexing='ij')

    # llenado sistema de ecuaciones
    N=Nx*Ny
    A=np.zeros((N,N))
    b=np.zeros(N)

    # londiciones de frontera
    T1=25
    T2=25
    T3=500
    T4=25

    # llenado del sistema
    for i in range(Nx):
        for j in range(Ny):
            n=i+j*Nx
    # esquina 1
    if i==0 and j==0:
        A[n][n]=1/dx**2+1/dy**2
        A[n][n+1]=-2/dx**2
        A[n][n-+2]=1/dx**2
        A[n][n+Nx]=-2/dy**2
        A[n][n+2*Nx]=1/dy**2
    # esquina 2
    elif i==Nx-1 and j==0:
        A[n][n]=1/dx**2+1/dy**2
        A[n][n-1]=-2/dx**2
        A[n][n-2]=1/dx**2
        A[n][n+Nx]=-2/dy**2
        A[n][n+2*Nx]=1/dy**2
    # esquina 3
    elif i==Nx-1 and j==Ny-1:
        A[n][n]=1/dx**2+1/dy**2
        A[n][n-1]=-2/dx**2
        A[n][n-2]=1/dx**2
        A[n][n-Nx]=-2/dy**2
        A[n][n-2*Nx]=1/dy**2
    # esquina 4
    elif i==0 and j==Ny-1:
        A[n][n]=1/dx**2+1/dy**2
        A[n][n+1]=-2/dx**2
        A[n][n+2]=1/dx**2
        A[n][n-Nx]=-2/dy**2
        A[n][n-2*Nx]=1/dy**2
    # lado 1
    elif 0<i<Nx-1 and j==0:
        A[n][n]=1
        b[n]=T1
    # lado 2
    elif i==Nx-1 and 0<j<Ny-1:
        A[n][n]=1
        b[n]=T2
    # lado 3
    elif 0<i<Nx-1 and j==Ny-1:
        A[n][n]=1
        b[n]=T3
    # lado 4
    elif i==0 and 0<j<Ny-1:
        A[n][n]=1
        b[n]=T4
    # nodos centrales
    else:
        A[n][n]=-2/dx**2-2/dy**2
        A[n][n+1]=1/dx**2
        A[n][n-1]=1/dx**2
        A[n][n+Nx]=1/dy**2
        A[n][n-Nx]=1/dy**2
        
    T=np.dot(np.linalg.inv(A),b)

    Tmesh=np.zeros((Nx,Ny))

    for n in range(N):}
        i=n%Nx
        j=n/Nx
        Tmesh[i][j]=T[n]

    plt.contourf(xmesh,ymesh,Tmesh)
```

Al momento de correrlo me sale el siguiente anuncio:
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

El código hace referencia a la transferencia de calor a lo largo de una placa rectangular plana

¡Gracias!

Al momento de correrlo me sale el siguiente anuncio:
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

El código hace referencia a la transferencia de calor a lo largo de una placa rectangular plana

¡Gracias!

Al momento de correrlo me sale el siguiente anuncio:
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

El código hace referencia a la transferencia de calor a lo largo de una placa rectangular plana

¡Gracias!

Comment: Mejor que indicar lo que intentas hacer, sería de mucha mas ayuda saber **en que línea exacta** se produce el error.

Comment: Si, Es verdad me aparece además esto: line 93, in <module>
    Tmesh[i][j]=T[n]